# How to set an Integer field value null or remove it in mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

In my application, mongoDB is not updating any field to null due to restriction on field types. So I generally set string fields to blank string, but same can not be done for integer fields. I wanted to know how to set any field to null (or remove it completely) in MongoDB.

Comment: I suspect that you are using schema that define/enforce the field type. By right, the collection is without schema, you are allowed to set the field with any value or even null. For removing the field value, you can use `$unset` operator. `{ $unset: { "Your_field": 1 } }`

Comment: @YongShun, Yes we are using json file to define a schema and this very same json file is being used to generate POJOs. Finally values from POJO being persisted in DB.

Comment: In that case, you may consider to [change the schema](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/schema-validation/update-schema-validation/)

Comment: $unset worked for removing the filed itself. That is what we wanted. Thanks!